# UNIX how to remove a line which has only comma and space

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, sed

UNIX how to remove a line which has only comma and space
Taking below example

```
dfasdfs,fasfsafsaf,dfasfasfs,sfd
dsfsafsa,fsafafsad
safsafas,fsafsaf,
 ,,,
asfdasf,asdfddsfas,
```

I need to remove [ ,,, ] line. Please note a space may occur in begin or end or in between

```
sed -i '/^[ ,]*$/d' file --- > Didn't work
```

can you please assist ? Thanks

Comment: Your `sed` command should work fine if there are only spaces around commas. Can you show output of `cat -vte file`

Comment: What does `Didn't work` mean? No output, wrong output, error messages, something else? When you take your car to the garage to get it fixed do you just tell the mechanic it `Didn't work` then turn and walk away and expect him to figure out the problem from that and fix it? When you need help solving a problem, it's best to provide all the information you have that might help diagnose the problem rather than the least information you could provide.

Comment: Seconding Ed.  "Didn't work" is not a bug report.  Your example there works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just use grep:

```
grep '[^ ,]' file
```

With sed that'd be:

```
sed -n '/[^ ,]/p' file
```

Note that that will also remove blank lines, let us know if that's an issue.

Comment: Hello, the sed option worked for me, but, what do "/p" mean at the end of the regex? tkx

Comment: `man sed` or just google sed. `p` should be easy to find (hint - the `-n` is relevant too).

Comment: thanks "/p": Write the pattern space to standard output if a replacement was made.  If the replacement string is identical to that which it replaces, it is still considered to have been a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

With grep:

```
grep -v '^[ ,]*$' file
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
awk ' { if ( $1 !~ /^[ ,]/ ) { print } ; } ' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/[[:space:],]/d' file.txt
```

Use option -i to persist these changes:

```
sed -i '/[[:space:],]/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me `sed -i '/^ [ ,]*$/d' file`.

Comment: That will fail for lines that don't start with a blank char.

Comment: Of course, but his example file looks like '[a-z],*'. At least there are only `,` or `[a-z],*`. And I understood him, that `[a-z]` could miss and beeing replaced by spaces. I copied his example and it worked with my sed command.